# Is it legal to carry a child around in a “close to you” child carrier?

Tags: united-states, children

While in a car, a child must be in a special seat. When I leave the car must I take the child seat (it’s detachable) with me together with the child. Or is it okay to place child in a “close to me” child carrier (image below). Suppose the child is a 7 pound newborn (10 days old).  Is it okay to carry the child in the street and in the hospital inside of this carrier? Or should it be a “car seat” type carrier?

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to ask in [parenting.se], or are you actually looking for a legal view on this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's more relevant on https://parenting.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If what is wanted is a legal answer, this is the right place for it. If what is wanted is parenting advice, migration would be advisable. This is on-topic here, no need to close unless the OP says parenting advice is what is wanted.

Comment: I need a legal answer. from the legal standpoint. The hospital was insisting to use car seat. This doesn’t make sense to me. They said it is a federal law. Outside the car, still car seat????? They said yes. Even outside the car there should be a SEAT not CARRY. So i need a legal advice

Comment: While this is on topic, a State tag  would be helpful.

Comment: This just seems like a standard "insane bureaucracy" thing. Not the part where they require you to do a certain thing for safety -- I'm not qualified to judge that -- but the part where they lie about (or misunderstand) where the requirement comes from, and falsely claim that it's a law to make you go away.

Comment: @user36842: I don't have the answer, but you've encountered something that is a significant problem with many hospitals. There are many people that don't own cars, intending on carrying their children home, getting gruff from the hospital when leaving because they don't have a carseat and don't intend to get one. You're not alone.

Comment: *The hospital was insisting to use car seat.* What happens if you do not have a car?

Comment: @WoJ if you're transporting in a car, you need the infant in a car seat.   If taxiing or Uber etc, request one with a car seat (and pay extra) or request one where you can fit your own car seat.  It is totally reasonable to own a carseat and not a car.

Comment: @Criggie I understand that you may want to own a carseat even if your do not have a car. That's a choice. What I do not get is how a hospital can *request* a carseat to enter their premises. Next thing they will request is an astronaut suit :) I am sure that in NZ you transport babies also in other devices such as strollers or close-to-body child carriers.

Comment: @WoJ just making the point that car ownership is not mandatory, but protecting your child is.  Most first world nations have some kind of carseat lease too - A parent may rent a carseat for a couple years for less than purchase cost, and return it when kid grows too big or swap it for the larger size, or a booster.

Comment: @Criggie: it must be a cultural thing then. In France, we do not default to transporting a child in a carseat (except in a car of course). We can do this occasionally for convenience but other means of transport (stroller, holder) are typical. From this perspective *requiring* someone to transport their child in a carseat seems extraordinary.

Comment: @woj I never said that - I said its okay and normal to own/possess/use a carseat even if you don't own a car.  That's all.

Comment: @Criggie No-one said it wasn't. No-one claimed that owning a carseat, but not a car was weird/abnormal. WoJ was pointing out that *expecting* everyone to have a carseat whether or not they have a car *is* weird.

Comment: When the hospital was insisting this was a federal law, which federal law were they able to quote? If a hospital tried to hit me with a barrier like that, I'd be insisting they produced a lawyer or a relevant director to explain…

Comment: The comments are a long string of questions asking for clarification on why you're asking and why the question even makes any sense to ask. Please edit the title and question to clarify this, because otherwise people have to read the comments to understand what this is about.

Comment: I feel like information and context is being drip-fed here. _"The hospital was insisting to use car seat"_ In what context are we talking? Were you taking a baby into the hospital as a patient? Were you the patient? (This makes sense, i.e. where would you put the baby while being examined yourself?) Were you visiting someone else? Is this regarding the baby leaving the hospital after being born? ... Context matters here.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is no legal reason that you can't carry your baby any way you want outside of your vehicle (as long as you aren't physically harming the child). Baby slings or "baby wearing" is recognized by many pediatric doctors as not just good for the child, but good for the parent too ([read more](https://childrensmd.org/browse-by-age-group/newborn-infants/should-you-wear-a-baby-sling/)).

Some hospitals (it was this way for my children) won't let you leave the hospital after birth without placing the child in an approved child seat. This is hospital policy though, not law. The purpose here was to verify that you are capable of putting your child in the seat, have the seat restraints positioned correctly, and understand the placement in the vehicle. Improper use can result in injury or death and this is a lot easier to examine in the hospital room than it is in your car.

Comment: Okay that’s why they were saying a car seat. Doesn’t make sense to me t. Why do i need the “carrying “ thingy then??? I guess i have to use the car seat after all

Comment: I would talk to your pediatrician. Newborns are especially fragile so there may be a "minimum age" to be putting them in certain slings, but now this is getting into parenting and not legal, if you have further questions on slings and their use I recommend https://parenting.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @user36842 people often say that something is required by law even when it isn't, whether as a lie or through a misunderstanding, misinformation, or what have you.  Often it's best just to take the path of least resistance and humor them.

Comment: @user36842 Some people find a detachable seat top convenient for bringing the child in from the car, such as if they're sleeping and removing them from the seat would wake them. It has nothing to do with legality though.

Comment: "won't let you leave the hospital" -- some poor parents who use transit, don't drive or take taxis, and don't have a car seat must still be stuck in the hospital room raising their 10-year-old...

Comment: @nanoman I say this as someone who doesn't have a car, most parents are going to have some sort of plan for getting home from the hospital that involves somebody's car—people who have just given birth aren't usually interested in riding the bus. There are often programs available, though they can be tricky to find, through prenatal care or a social worker or Medicaid, or even insurance companies to [provide car seats to those in need](https://safeconvertiblecarseats.com/blog/free-car-seats/).

Comment: @ZachLipton In dense cities, some live on the same block as their hospital and would just walk home, no?

Comment: (I've personally seen a small hospital on the north side of Chicago with residential buildings directly across the street, so the above comment is not just speculation; such things do very much exist).

Comment: @nanoman: If you tell them that they'll activate the appropriate variant of their policy. However, a ride in a taxi or public transit **does** require (in terms of safety, and I believe legally) a proper carseat. Only walking would not strictly require it, but even then a stroller with detachable carseat would be desirable.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Taxi, yes, that's why I specified no driving or taxis. [Transit, no](https://grist.org/living/whats-the-safest-way-to-take-my-baby-on-the-bus/): "And you don’t have to worry about lugging a car seat to do it, as most buses and trains lack the seat belts necessary to lock them in place... Lots of commuting parents swear by a front pack, baby wrap, or sling..."

Comment: What does this mean 'wont let you leave the hospital'? Isnt this called false imprisonment and carries a hefty fine? Or is the child hold hostage? I do not understand how this can be possible.

Comment: @nanoman: Even not locked into place, a carseat is a much safer place for a newborn to be in a vehicle than loose or strapped to a person, where sudden deceleration could lead to crushing injuries.

Comment: *Some hospitals (it was this way for my children) won't let you leave the hospital after birth without placing the child in an approved child seat.* A strong suggestion from them may be good, but if a hospital ever really does try to block someone from taking their child with them, without a court order or a current medical emergency or something, this is generally a serious crime.  (And a current medical emergency may not authorize the hospital to do this either, but you get the idea - this is not in their day-to-day authority.)

Comment: @RonBeyer _Newborns are especially fragile_ I think that that's a common misconception, but I'm not sure. Do you know of any evidence to back it up?

Comment: @sgf my sister fell off her changing table (from a height of maybe a meter or a bit more, I suppose) at a very young age (not newborn, however) and was fine.  So yes, babies are not as fragile as they're often thought to be.  But newborns _are_ more fragile than older children in certain respects, most notably their necks.  The related risk posed by a baby sling is suffocation; see for example https://www.cpsc.gov/Newsroom/News-Releases/2017/CPSC-Approves-New-Federal-Safety-Standard-for-Infant-Sling-Carriers

Answer (score 23):

### *Hospital discharge* is a legally recognized event/act

... in which the hospital determines the patient no longer requires in-hospital care. Hospitals are under extreme scrutiny regarding discharge practices, in part [due to racist history](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0272989X07302130) of discharging indigent or suspected-nonpaying patients prematurely.  Further, they face consderable civil liability for a wrongful discharge.

### Discharge planning is a mandatory part of hospital policy

Hospitals which wish to accept Medicaid patients must meet particular requirements outlined in [42 CFR 482.43](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/42/482.43):  (excerpting):

> The discharge planning process and the discharge plan must be consistent with the patient's goals for care and his or her treatment preferences, ensure an effective transition of the patient from hospital to post-discharge care, and **reduce the factors leading to preventable hospital readmissions**.

This *requires* the hospital to have a discharge plan for mothers which assures the child is going into a safe environment.

This applies to hospitals who want to take part in the Medicare system. That will be every public or government-run hospital, as well as any other hospital unable to survive exclusively on private-insurer patients. Remember, hospitals *can't turn away* patients who are not stable enough to move or legally discharge, so they are stuck with a great many Medicare patients. Might as well get paid for them rather than try to pursue out-of-network payment from either Medicare or the patient directly.

You could say "Well, the hospital could refuse Medicare business, and tell the government to stuff it."  That's true. However, when they find themselves in a malpractice lawsuit with a *private* patient, the plaintiffs certainly could compare this hospital's "best practices" with those of the industry at large.  If the hospital's fell short, that would hurt them badly in the lawsuit. The excuse of "Well, those other hospitals only do that to pursue Medicaid money" would be a very poor sell for the ears of a jury.

So effectively, the Federal government "wags the dog": while it only has the legal reach to set standards for its own vendors, *so many* are its vendors that it can effectively set the industry standard *nonetheless*.  Of course this isn't cloaked men in a "star chamber" deciding this; these regulations are arrived that in a highly public process.  And most people involved in the process are highly favorable toward such policies.

### Baby policy is very much part of that discharge planning

As for encouraging mothers to use proper car seats, the University of Maryland public  health law attorneys [did a brief on the issue](https://www.law.umaryland.edu/media/SOL/pdfs/Programs/Public-Health-Law/Car_Seat_Issue_BRief.pdf).  It identifies the issue as "A major public-health imperative".  Down on page 8 it says:

> Hospitals that fail to provide a certain level of CPS education and support can face liability under state medical malpractice laws and common law principles. Providers of medical care are liable if a patient is injured because of the providers' violation of the standard of care, which varies within each state and for each medical profession, but is generally determined through expert witness testimony on what a typical provider of the same specialty and training would do in the same situation.

That last sentence goes back to what I said about Medicaid "wagging the dog" by defining what typical providers do.

They cannot hold you prisoner.  You always have the option to leave the hospital without proper discharge.  If you do leave without proper discharge, that relieves them of liability.

As you very well know, you [must use a proper child safety seat](https://www.verywellfamily.com/us-car-seat-laws-by-state-4082814).  As I show above, the hospital has a duty to assure they are releasing the child into a safe situation. So it is entirely reasonable for them to ask, and you must put up with this.  **However, the hospital is not entitled to "make up" requirements where state law or other competent body has already defined them**... so if state law, Underwriter's Laboratories (a nonprofit), NHSTA, etc. defines what a proper safety seat is (or APTA defines what safe baby travel on public transit is), that's the last word.

There is no scenario here where you get to leave in an automobile without a proper
safety seat.  If you're in a transit-rich city where a carless mom and "going home on the Metro" is a likely scenario, they should be satiated by showing them your transit pass and that you are equipped with whatever transit agencies require for that use.

If push comes to shove, they can't hold your child hostage - but if you're down to pushing and shoving, they *could* pull a CPS (Child Protective Services) officer into the conversation, "merely in a consulting capacity, of course".  The hospital will do whatever CPS tells them to do.  *As will you*.

Comment: This describes why hospitals have certain discharge policies, but doesn't seem to answer the question of the legal obligations of the parent.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I think the last paragraph hits on it.  If you want to leave the hospital using the baby carrier OP is talking about, legally the hospital can't stop you. However, they will ask you to sign a form waiving your rights to sue in the event something happens due to discharge. Assuming the parents aren't driving away from the hospital, the parent is not legally obligated to use Car Carrier XYZ, or anything. The *hospital* has the legal obligations.

Comment: I also edited onto the end, starting with "as you very well know" - there's no evidence here that OP doesn't know the child-seat-in-cars law.

Comment: "Hospitals are under extreme scrutiny regarding discharge practices, in part due to racist history of discharging indigent or suspected-nonpaying patients prematurely." I can't see where to read the full text of that journal article, but does it actually show any evidence that early discharges were the reason why Black stroke patients died more often after discharge than White patients were? From what's written on the page you linked to, it seems entirely possible that there might be some biological reason for it -eg maybe the genes for sickle cell anemia make you more likely to die of stroke.

Comment: @nick012000 racist/biased actions in healthcare are *extremely* well-documented. Basically if you're not an average white male in the United States, it's less likely that you'll get quality medical treatment. *Most* of the time doctors simply believe women/minorities are making stuff up or are delusional. TBH "extreme scrutiny" is the part of that statement that I'm skeptical of, not the biased discharge practices.

Comment: @WayneWerner What I mean is a) it's the subject of a great deal of study, and b) lawyers are working pretty hard to fish for new patients in the "premature discharge" area, it was difficult to research, for all the lawyer ads.  Obviously it's a target-rich environment.

Comment: Ah, so specifically scrunity by lawyers (hoping to sue for damages)? Now _that_ I have no problem believing (and, they should -- discrimination is horrible, especially that results in loss of life. Though, it does have a tendency to produce CYA policies like car seats for discharge)

Comment: @WayneWerner It's hardly *just* CYA... if you read the literature, it's also astonishingly good public policy.  Pay now or pay later - $50 worth of Mom orientation now saves $5 million in public funds for lifetime care of a disabled citizen who was maimed as an infant.

Comment: @WayneWerner Sure, that might be true, but the link was given in the post to show that doesn't support that case. It just shows a disparity in outcomes without explaining why that disparity is there.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica whether or not the *outcomes* are good (which they are), the fact that this discussion is happening in the first place means that not everyone involved actually understands. If you don't understand why and you're still doing it to avoid legal trouble, it's CYA.